# awss3transfermanager background uploads success but not in bucket

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, awss3transfermanager

I am using AWSS3TransferManager to upload files directly to s3. I am getting a success message back from the upload block but it isn't appearing in my bucket in the s3 management console. When I visit the url directly it appears though. I need this to be added to the bucket because my app pulls from an sqs queue in order to create the object in the db.

Here is my code for uploading:

```
let uploadFileRequest = AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest()
uploadFileRequest.bucket = AWS.S3BucketName


uploadFileRequest.key = uploadFileName
uploadFileRequest.contentType = "video/quicktime"
uploadFileRequest.contentLength = NSNumber(integer: video!.length)

let transferManager = AWSS3TransferManager.defaultS3TransferManager()
uploadFileRequest.body = uploadFileURL! 

transferManager.upload(uploadFileRequest).continueWithBlock({ (task) -> AnyObject! in
     if task.error != nil {
        print("video upload failed \(task.error)")
     } else {
        print("video upload succeeded")
        print("\(uploadFileName)")

     }
     return 1
})
```

update: 
I think this may be a security issue. Here is my code for setting up cognito:
let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:

```
AWSRegionType.USEast1, identityPoolId: AWS.cognitoPoolID)
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)
AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by not appearing on console but appears through the link. Also, have you tried using AWSS3TransferUtility for Background Transfers? This is a link to the sample app which can help you: https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3BackgroundTransfer-Sample/Swift Thanks!

Comment: When I visit the url it appears and loads fine but inside the management console looking through the files it doesn't appear. Is using getPresignedURLRequest along with nsurlsession not the recommended way to do this anymore? Haven't tried the transfer utility but I will give that a shot right now. Thanks! Edit: Also is there a way to attach metadata using AWSS3TransferUtility?

Comment: Trying to use AWSS3TransferUtilityUploadExpression() and adding the meta data to that like so: expression.setValue(session_id!, forRequestParameter:AWS.S3MetadataSessionID  ) and doesn't seem to be working?

Comment: The transfer utility upload takes an expression object. You can add metadata to the expression by calling – setValue:forRequestParameter:.

Comment: Yes I figured that out... I think in the documentation somewhere it should say one must add x-amz-meta- as a prefix